# Tiles 2 won't load when called from inside subfolders

Tags: web-applications, servlets, spring-mvc, tiles2

I have these odd problem with my webapp. When I access ***home.jsp*** or ***example.jsp***, Tiles is loaded normally, but when I want to access ***example2.jsp***, inside as subfolder, the layout is not called at all.

My **directory structure** is as follows:

```
webapp
  |___ pages
           |___ subfolder
                      |___ example2.jsp
           |___ tiles
                  |___ layouts
                         |___ base-layout.jsp
                  |___ header.jsp
                  |___ footer.jsp
           |___ example.jsp
           |___ home.jsp
  |___ resources
  |___ WEB-INF
           |___ servlet.xml
           |___ tiles-defs.xml
           |___ web.xml
  |___ index.jsp
```

My **servlet.xml**

```
<!-- JSP View Resolver -->  
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<!-- Default Tiles View Resolver -->    
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/> 
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean> 

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" >
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My **tiles-defs.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>

  <definition name="base-layout" template="/pages/tiles/layouts/base-layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/pages/tiles/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/pages/tiles/footer.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="home" extends="base-layout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Title" /> 
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/home.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="example1" extends="base-layout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Title" /> 
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/example.jsp" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="example2" extends="base-layout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Title" /> 
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/subfolder/example2.jsp" />
  </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

My **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working by commenting the **viewClass** line inside the **InternalResourceViewResolver**.

The final code is as follows:

```
<!-- JSP View Resolver -->  
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<!-- <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> -->
<property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
<property name="order" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I access home.jsp or example.jsp, [snip] but when I want to access example2.jsp [snip]

What are the urls you are using for each of these requests?

Your spring DispatcherServlet is configured against requests that match *.html urls. All other urls won't initialise tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I solved it by commenting a line of the JSP view resolver.